# Windows Phone: Request with self signed server

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, rest, ssl-certificate

My Windows Phone application consumes data from a remote service, which is using Apache Tomcat. Until now every call to the service was made using *http://* protocol but recently the service developer added a security layer and now I have to make requests using *https://* protocol.

I know that the default behavior of Windows Phone is to avoid every self-signed certificate and the optimal situation would be having a certificate signed by a Certification Authority, but I haven't it. Searching in the web I found that it is possible to install a self-signed certificate on a WP device, there are two options:

1. Send a mail and attach the *.cer* file. When we try to open it WP starts the installation process.
2. Put the *.cer* file in a public space of the server, accessible by *http://* protocol. On the applications first launch we try to open its URL with the device browser and WP starts the installation process.

The b option is less annoying for the user so I am doing that way.

I create the ***.cer file using Internet Explorer on my PC. I don’t know if I am doing this step well. I know that it is possible to export using Mozilla Firefox, but it has not the *.cer* file format in the list.

The request to the service is returning this error:
“The remote server returned an error: NotFound.”

This is the approach I used when security was not implemented:

```
public void Start()
{
    String requestString = url + method + parameters;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(requestString);
    request.BeginGetResponse(FinishHttpWebRequest, request);
}

public void FinishHttpWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    if (request != null)
    {
         try
         {
               WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
               Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
               string responseString = new StreamReader(streamResponse).ReadToEnd();
         }
         catch (WebException e)
         {
                …
         }
     }
 }
```

For developing I send the *.cer* file by mail and open it using Windows Phone Emulator and Windows Phone tells that the installation was successful but still with the error.

Those are the options I am using:

Option A. Exactly the same approach as with *http* protocol

```
private void Start(string url)
{
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
     request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
     request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
     request.BeginGetResponse(FinishWebRequest, request);
}


public void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
     HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
     if (request != null)
     {
          try
          {
                WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseString = new StreamReader(streamResponse).ReadToEnd();
          }
          catch (WebException ex)
          {
             …
          }
     }
 }
```

Option B. With web client

```
private WebClient myWebClient;

public void Start(string requestString)
{
     myWebClient = new WebClient();
     myWebClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCompleted);
     myWebClient.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri(requestString));
}

void DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         string Text = e.Result;
     }
     catch
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

Option 3
Very similar to the example at the bottom of [the msdn page of httpwebrequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and also very similar of option 1.

What am I missing? Is correct the certification installation?

If you need more info please ask for it

Your help is appreciated.

EDIT 2013/07/18 
I add more info, I think it is usable.

The steps I follow to export to *.CER* file with Microsoft Internet Explorer (my Windows installation is not in English so I am sure not every option is exactly as I write), similar to:

1. Open the *https://myWebApp.com*
2. Loads the window: "There is a problem with this website's security certificate"
3. Click "Continue to this website"
4. On the top I click "See Certificates"
5. Execute "Copy in file" in the Details tab.
6. Send the resultant file by mail and open it in the Windows Phone simulator.

I don't know if the certificate must be in the root authority certifications previous exporting it, I do not know.

The WebException ex I am getting has the following data:

Message:

```
   "The remote server returned an error: NotFound."
```

Status:

```
   UnknownError
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at MyApp.Model.Webservice.SecureRestClient.FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

EDIT 2

In the document Windows® Phone 7 and certificates says that is recommended to restart the device to activate the recently installed certificates.

I send the certificate to my HTC Radar and the installation is successful. But when I open *https://myWebApp.com* with Internet Explorer loads the window: "There is a problem…”  so I think I am missing something while exporting the *.cer* file.

EDIT 3

Now it is  posible to debug on a device ([unlocking steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)), but the situation does not change.
Do you need more info? What am I missing? I always get the not found exception.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try export your certificate to P7B file and import it on Windows Phone. 
[More details here](http://www.markermetro.com/2013/06/technical/dealing-with-self-signed-ssl-certificates-on-windows-phone/)

Comment: I will try it when I have some free time. Thank you for your help